# How to vary the arguments in multiprocessing.Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I want to execeute yapsy-plugins with the help of multiprocessing in python. So far i've got a worker as follows:

```
def mp_worker(plugin, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb):
    print(" Processs " + plugin.plugin_object.getOrigin + " running.")
    processPlugin(plugin, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb)
    print(" Process " + plugin.plugin_object.getOrigin + " done.")
```

The plugin parameter is a plugin object. The function processPlugin does the necessary work but istn relevant for the question.

My handler for the multiprocessing is where i stuck:

```
def mp_handler(plugins, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool.map(mp_worker(???)
```

I am giving it an array with the plugin objects called plugins, but obviously the workers need different plugins. How to achieve a pool with this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a little time of testing i figured out how it would work, if it wouldnt be a yapsy plugin class:

```
    def mp_worker(importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb, plugin):
        processPlugin(plugin, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb)


    def mp_handler(plugins, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    func = partial(mp_worker, importer, orgadb, regiondb, ispdb)
    pool.map(func, plugins)
    pool.close()
```

Anyway pickle doesnt work with the plugin class so anyone who wants to multiprocess  yapsy plugins also has to take a look at this:
http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/MultiprocessPluginProxy.html